# Flasgger: How to write description of several endpoints in one yaml file?

Tags: python-3.x, api, yaml, swagger, flasgger

I created several endpoints in Flask and created yml files for each of them. So, for example I have 10 endpoints and 10 small yaml files. It is not very comfort to use it, so I want put all the descriprions into 1 yml file.
I tried this:
app script:

```
from flask import Flask, jsonify, abort, make_response, request
from flasgger import Swagger, swag_from

app = Flask(__name__)
swagger = Swagger(app)

@app.route('/api/test/<int:ids>', methods=['GET'])
@swag_from('app.yml')
def test(ids):
    """
    Test function
    Some test function for debugging Swagger.
    """
    return jsonify({"var1": 12312300, "var2":"sdfsdf"})

@app.route('/api/test2/<int:var>', methods=['GET'])
@swag_from('app.yml')
def test(var):
    """
    Test function 2
    Some test function for debugging Swagger.
    """
    abort(make_response(jsonify(message="There is no model with this index"), 404))
```

and my `app.yml`:

```
paths:
  /api/test2/<int:var>:
    get:
      return some information
      ---
      tags:
        - stage1:
        - name: var
          description: ID
          in: path
          required: true
          type: integer
      responses:
        200:
          description:  OK.


  /api/test/<int:ids>:
    get:
      Test function
      Some test function for debugging Swagger.
      ---
      tags:
        - stage1
      parameters:
        - name: ids
          description: ID
          in: path
          required: true
          type: integer
      responses:
        200:
          description:  OK.
        405:
          description: Invalid input
```

But this throw the error:

> Errors Fetch errorINTERNAL SERVER ERROR /apispec_1.json

this mean something wrong in my `yml` file. **How to write it correctly?**

---

I found such issue on the github:
https://github.com/rochacbruno/flasgger/issues/264

Comment: any update on the solution ???

Answer (score 1):

You can build swagger like this but, before init swagger, you should make sure that the method `register_blueprint` has been called.

```
def init(app: Flask):
    # yaml path
    conf_path = os.path.abspath(__file__)
    conf_path = os.path.dirname(conf_path)
    conf_path = os.path.join(conf_path, 'swagger.yml')
    swagger = Swagger(app=app, template_file=conf_path)
```